# Add some custom fields in Views exposed filters and preserve their data to Url (GET)

Tags: 7, views

I have a Views list of Boats and every Content Type 'boat' has a location. So I have created an exposed form that already contains a location `<select>`, and when changed, the boats are successfully filtered by the location selected. 
I want to put other inputs in this form, like:

- Check in Date
- Check out Date
- Number of visitors

But these data are not filters, they are just input that can be used in the next step (explained later).

1. Is there a simple way to add these custom fields in the exposed filter form (or look like being inside it somehow)?
2. How to retrieve this information, so when a specific boat is selected (that's the next step) the number of visitors,check in/out dates, etc will be shown in a similar form (Webform) which finally sends a mail..

Thanks in advance!

PS: I am a newbie on both Drupal and Drupal Answers! 
I've searched but I am confused whether I should create a custom module or use an existing one that I currently am unaware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it! I got to the the Views' theme folder and did what exactly I show [here](http://timonweb.com/how-display-views-exposed-filter-block-and-theme-it)!

Then the data-passing through different pages needs some script and is done!